# ¿cómo abrir y mostrar un directorio con AJAX y glob PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

En un directorio tengo dos archivos php y varias carpetas numeradas secuencialmente. En el primer archivo paso una variable númerica mediante un formulario, que abrirá un directorio en el segundo archivo mediante la función glob. Estoy tratando de mostrar el contenido de estas carpetas con AJAX sin refrescar la página, pero el código no funciona. La idea es instalar después un plugin tipo lightbox para dar un formato como galería.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AXAX1</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$path = "thumb/";
$files = scandir($path);
$num_files = count($files)-2;
?>

<div class="container">
    <?php
    for($a = 0; $a < $num_files; $a++) :
    ?>
    <form action="GALLERY2.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="var" value="<?php echo $a; ?>">
        <input type="image" name="submit" src="thumb/gA<?php echo $a; ?>.jpg" height=100>
    </form>   
    <?php
    endfor; ?>
</div>

<div id="display">
</div> 
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "GALLERY2.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {
                    $.each(json, function(i, val) {
                        if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i).test(this)) { 
                            $("#display").append('<img src="'+this+'"/>');
                        }else if (!(/\.(mp4)$/i).test(this)) { 
                            $("#display").append('<video src="'+this+'"/>');
                        }; 
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>         
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$variable = $_POST['var'];
$img_dir = $variable . "/";
echo json_encode (glob($img_dir . '*.jpg'));
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El `JS` de tu pregunta da error de sintaxis ya que te esta faltando cerrar las funciones: `.ready, .submit y .ajax`. También puedo ver que dentro de `success:` no deberías hacer un `jQuery.parseJSON` y al iterar usando [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) estas tomando valor incorrectos, lee la documentación y corrige esa parte.

Comment: He modificado el código, indicado un índice y un valor para iterar apropiadamente. También cerré todas las funciones. Sigo sin entender como devolver json a través de Ajax.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta, agrega el código actualizado. En lo posible, también el `JSON` que recibes de `GALLERY2.php`

Comment: Tengo tres carpetas llamadas 0, 1, 2. En cada una de ellas tengo algunos archivos jpg. Si ejecuto el código y hago click en el primer input, recibo un recorrido por todos los archivos de la primera carpeta. Esto no es por Ajax, ya que la página se vuelve a cargar. Adjunto una imagen.

Comment: Es decir el código funciona, pero es como si Ajax no estuviera. No recibo error pero me devuelve la página 2.php.

Answer (score 2):

> Tu código aún tenia los siguientes errores:
>
> - Faltaba cerrar el método `.ready`. Es por esta razón que el formulario se enviaba redireccionandote a `GALERIA2.php`.
> - En la llamada `ajax` no estabas enviado los datos (`data`).
> - En el `success`, al iterar usando `$.each`, la variable `json` no existe y no deberías hacer `.test(this)`.
> - Al agregar las imagenes y videos, te esta faltando concatenar el directorio (`folder`).

Intenta hacerlo así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    // Buscamos los datos del form.
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajax({
      url: "GALLERY2.php",
      data: data, // Los enviamos
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        // Creamos un variable para agregar el directorio
        var folder = data.var + '/',
          html = '';
        $.each(response, function(i, val) {

          if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i).test(val)) {
            // Concatenamos el directorio
            html += '<img src="'+folder+val+'"/>';
          }
          else if (!(/\.(mp4)$/i).test(val)) { 
            html += '<video src="'+folder+val+'"/>';
          }
        });
        $("#display").html(html);
      }
    });
  });
}); // Faltaba cerrar este metodo
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos Gallardo. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es una galería con niveles de profundidad. He modificado un poco el código. Agregué una carpeta llamada thumb en el directorio. Cambié los input submit por input image. Vinculé estos input con la carpeta thumb. También cambié la parte da Ajax, optimizándola mejor.

Comment: Me queda la duda de como limpiar el div cada vez que hago la petición por Ajax. He intentado utilizando `$("#display").html('<img src="'+val+'" height=100/>');`  en lugar de `$("#display").append('<img src="'+val+'" height=100/>');` pero no funciona bien.

Comment: @virtual8870, he actualizado mi respuesta para darte una solución a este nuevo problema.

Comment: Ahora sí. Yo tengo todas las carpetas y los archivos php en un mismo directorio, entonces me basta solo la variable val en img/video src. Muchas gracias.